# Jetty Set up Servlet to Communicate with JSP Page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jetty

I am very new to JSP and Jetty, and I am really confused why this code does not work.

This is my Main class

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Server server = new Server(8080);

        // As we are using the Servlet to server responses remove the resource
        // handler.
        ResourceHandler resource_handler = new ResourceHandler();
        resource_handler.setDirectoriesListed(true);
        resource_handler.setWelcomeFiles(new String[] { "index.jsp",
                "index.html" });
        resource_handler.setResourceBase("./target/classes/webapp");

        // Initialise Servlet context handler
        ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(
                ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);

        context.setContextPath("/");



        // Create WebAppContext for JSP files.
        WebAppContext webAppContext = new WebAppContext();
        webAppContext.setResourceBase("./target/classes/webapp");

        HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
        handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[] { webAppContext, context,
                resource_handler, new DefaultHandler() });
        server.setHandler(handlers);

        try {
            server.start();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }

    }
```

This is my servlet

```
public class IndexServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 0x1C30CCL;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // Set response content type.
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);

        request.setAttribute("message", "hello");


    }
```

}

This is my index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"%> 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Book a hotel!</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="index.jsp" method="post">
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter Username" />
<input type="Submit">
</form>
<p> The current local time at the hotel is: <%= new java.util.Date() %> </p>
    <h1>${message }</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

and this is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
 version="2.5">


<servlet>
    <servlet-class>ncl.raffaello.IndexServlet</servlet-class>
    <servlet-name>IndexServlet</servlet-name>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>IndexServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>index.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

My issue is that, though I know the .jsp works when I don't have a servlet, I want the servlet to set request variables, however when the servlet is enabled, like in my code samples it does not run any of the .jsp at all! Any help? I am at loss at what to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining a servlet with a mapping of /index.jsp as well as having a static welcome page by the same name.

When the container receives a request for /index.jsp it looks for the longest exact match, so it matches with the servlet and your doGet is called.

The container would only call the jsp if an exact match was not found, in which case it would match with *.jsp which is what the jsp processor will match to.

You have two choices:

1. Make the mapping for the servlet something other than index.jsp.
2. Put the jsp in a sub directory, for example "welcomes", so you define the welcome file as /welcome/index.jsp. Then any request to /index.jsp will go the servlet and a request to "/" would go to index.jsp.  The servlet can then forward the request to /welcomes/index.jsp and the jsp will be be called.

Comment: I did end up doing the latter and it works, my question is, is it possible to "intercept" the call when a GET request is sent, set some parameters then divert to that .jsp page with the same name which will then display that parameter.

Comment: Not unless the server provided some special customized way of doing it. Basically a server can't match the same uri (/index.jsp) to one resource for an inbound request and different resource for a forward request.

Comment: Okay, this is pretty informative, I'll mark your answer as accepted and opt for the second option. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

`PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
out.println("something")`  in your `sevlet` to print something on the `jsp` page.

Simple tutorial [here](http://crunchify.com/servlet-tutorial-getting-starting-with-jsp-servlet-example/).

Change your servlet mapping url pattern form `index.jsp` to `test`

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>IndexServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>test</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Modify your form action in index.jsp to `<form action="test">`

Build the project and start the server.

If you hit the url `localhost:8080`, you should get the index.jsp since you set it as `welcomePage`. If not try `localhost:8080/index.jsp`. You should get the form now.

If you submit the form, `IndexServlet` will be called

Comment: Sorry, the Sysout was just debug code. Doing that code, just prints out "something" to my page, it doesn't show the web form and the rest of the jsp

Comment: did you get the `index.jsp` with this url `localhost:8080/index.jsp`?

Comment: Yeah, i used that url